# Django redirect URL into another URL with form

Tags: python, django

I wouldlike to redirect in another URL when I submit my form.

[image]

After submit, I wouldike to have another page with something like "Hello (SummonerName) and Welcome" with URL like this : interface/main/SummonerName=(SummonerName)

Here my code :

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class SummonerForm(forms.Form):
summoner_name = form.CharField(label='SummonerName:', max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpresponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/interface/name.html')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'interface/main.html', {'form': form})
```

and my main.html

```
<form action="/SummonerName={{ current_name }}" method="post">
    <label for="summoner_name">SummonerName: </label>
    <input id="summoner_name" type="text" name="summoner_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Rechercher">
</form>
```

EDIT :

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = {
path('main', view.get_summoner_name)

}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

That is what `return HttpResponseRedirect` does your views.py. You only need to pass your desired url as the first parameter instead of `'/interface/name.html'.

See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses

For passing on the name, you have many options depending on what you want to do with the inputted data.

**A simple solution:**

Your example is rather simple and so if you only want to redirect to some url and show the name the user has inputed the easiest would be to pass the name (and any other parameters) via the url as a querystring:

```
import urllib.parse

# ... omitted code

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # get parameters from the form
            params = {
                "summoner_name" : form.validated_data["summoner_name"],
                # multiple parameters can be passed in this dict e.g.
                # "some_other param" : param_value
            }
            # encode the dictionary into a querystring
            q_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
            # construct the new URL:
            redirect_url = "/interface/success/?summoner_name={}".format(q_string)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'interface/main.html', {'form': form})
```

You can then access these parameters in your views/templates by the request object.

Then, in your urls.py you should match this url pattern by adding to your patterns something like:

```
path('interface/success/', views.success_view),
```

and you should of course define that view:

```
# views.py
def success_view(request):
    return render(request, "success.html")
```

Finally you should add a template `success.html`. There you could do `<h1> Hello {{ request.GET.summoner_name }}! </h1>`

**A more common usecase**

The method above only shows data the user has inputted which is usually not very usefull... More commonly in a form we ask data that we need to save to the db, and thats why I proposed a ModelForm in my comment. It is off the scope of this answer to explain exactly how that would work but in a nutshell: you should define a model in your models.py (i.e. a db table) where you can store data (summoner_name would be a field in such a model).

```
class SimpleModel(models.Model):
    summoner_name=models.CharField(max_length=256)
    # other fields you may need
```

Then you can use a django's generic class based views e.g.

```
class SimpleFormView(CreateView):
    model = SimpleModel
    success_url = "interface/success"
```

urls.py will also need some editing and your tempaltes should comply with django naming conentions too. Do read this if you want to go down that way:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#form-handling-with-class-based-views

Comment: I tried this: `return HttpResponseRedirect('/SummonerName=')` but after submit  page not found

Comment: I edited my answer. If you keep having difficulties, please post your urls.py too. As a general remark, you can probably save all this typing by using ModelForm and class based views. It requires a bit of learning how to use but it is definitely worth it as it simplifies such simple tasks for many use cases.

Comment: I just edited my post with urls.py. Sorry I started to learn Django 2 days ago... many things I don't know about this framework... As you want and it will be a pleasure for me if you have some recommandation to add with using ModelForm and class !

Comment: Hi ! sorry for my late response... I tried to modify my URL like this but it still doesn't work... path('main', views.get_name),
    path('success', views.success_view)

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What doesn't work? What happens exactly? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Always the same error, page not found and with url like this : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/SummonerName=" I put my project on github maybe It will be more clear if you have full source code : https://github.com/AC-1994/FALKON_ANALYTICS